# Using Activestorage (direct uploads) via API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'd like to use Rails as a backend to a mobile app (Android and maybe iOS), and one of the requirements is file upload.

I haven't been able to find any resources on using Activestorage with direct upload in this way – does anyone have an example or tips?

The alternative – I suppose – is to reverse-engineer activestorage.js and do exactly what it does. But perhaps I'm not the first one with this need...

Comment: hey please look at [link] (https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32208)

Comment: Hey i am looking for the same. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sorry, no. The project fell through and there is no need for me anymore. I'd still be interested in knowing how it can be done though – for the future.

Answer (score 1):

Rails does not care if your data is sent from a mobile-app, html-form, react-app, server-to-server...

If you can authenticate the request and send a multi-part file, then you do active-storage from your app.

Probably smart to look at gems/apps that do this already https://github.com/cbothner/react-activestorage-provider